# Recargar completamente el html para que se vuelva a ejecutar el ready() después de procesar la petición con Struts2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Trabajo con Struts2, tengo la situación donde mando el formulario al servidor y hago una validación, si la validación no es OK tengo que regresar a esa misma página.

El problema está que cuando regreso a la página por medio de un

```
<result name="FAIL" type="redirect-action">
    <param name="actionName">MiMismaClase</param>
</result>
```

como que no hace un verdadero redireccionamiento porque mi `$(document).ready(function())` ya no se ejecuta.

Entro por primera vez al flujo. Llego a MiMismaClase y en el execute se carga la vista y el controlador me devuelve mi JSP, mi JSP entra en acción y el document.ready de jquery se ejecuta perfectamente (un alert, por ejemplo), cuando mando el formulario y si las validaciones no son correctas tengo que volver al mismo jsp **pero requiero que se vuelva a ejecutar el ready**, hay alguna manera de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu acción implementa el método `validate()` que viene incluído en la interface `validateable`.

La lógica es:

1. Navegador pide la página.
2. Struts2 sirve la página.
3. Llenar forma.
4. Enviar forma desde el navegador (submit).
5. Struts2 corre el método `validate()`
6. Si la validación falla Struts2 regresa al paso 2.
7. Si la vaildación es exitosa la acción continua el proceso normal.